# How do I start developing for Windows Phone?

Tags: .net, windows-phone, microsoft-metro

I'm a software developer with 2 years of experience in web development using ASP.NET. I'm also a Microsoft Certified Technology Specialist for Web Development using .NET Framework 4.0.

My experience has only been with respect to web development; I have no idea at all regarding development of desktop or phone applications. Now, I'm very much interested in developing apps for Windows Phone (Metro-style apps or normal apps), because I'm currently jobless and would like to expand my skills so that I can get a job.

I was unable to find anything on the internet that suits my particular requirement. 
I'm a quick learner, so I just need some good and simple tutorials to get started with development for Windows Phone.

Could someone please provide links to few such tutorials? Also, is it possible for a person with experience only in web development, to learn app development for Windows Phone by himself?

Comment: If you are not able to find tutorials for Windows phone app development, I am afraid I have some more bad news: It is not possible to learn Windows phone app development by your own... Sorry... :(

Comment: You're off topic here, but there is a [free ebook for Windows phone 7 developers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/10/28/free-ebook-programming-windows-phone-7-by-charles-petzold.aspx) if thats helpful.

Comment: Sure you can move to mobile ,i moved from asp.net to windows 7 then to iOS. The problem is not sow much with learning new technologies as it is with a difrent mindset and thinking in terms of mobile device not of web

Comment: @Veger Your sarcasm is not required. I did find tutorials, but they all mentioned 'Windows 8 Metro-style apps, and no mention of 'Windows Phone'. That's the reason I was confused.

Comment: @RogerRowland I'm extremely sorry if this is off topic. First time I'm using this site, and I never got an option to post my question in any specific category. Please let me know the proper topic to post this question. Thank you.

Comment: A simple google seach for 'Windows phone 8 app development tutorial' got [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402529(v=vs.105).aspx) as a first hit. It does not contain the word 'metro'... The other hits also do not seem to be about about metro-style app development as well... So, it was not really sarcasm, I suppose. Nonetheless, best of luck with learning about this topic!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on below link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680270(v=pandp.11).aspx
look to it

Answer (score 0):

> Also, is it possible for a person with experience only in web development, to learn app development for Windows Phone by himself?

Sure it is. Obvious that any help is always welcome, but you can find some good tutorials and documentation around.

You'll need a copy of Windows 8 installed. If you don't have a full copy of Visual Studio you can use [Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-phone) and follow [some tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsphonetrainingcourse_basic_unit.aspx). Read the texts, study the examples and try to implement something for yourself. Good luck!

Comment: The link you provided is extremely helpful. Thanks a million. And I can only use Visual Studio Express because I reside in a third world country where a copy of Visual Studio is extremely expensive, and unaffordable by the common man.

Comment: Also, I need to know one more thing. Is it necessary to have Windows 8 installed even to develop apps for Windows Phone 7?

Comment: You can have more information [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570). But to develop for Windows Phone 8 you'll need Windows 8 Professional.

Comment: And since I'm from Brazil, I know how high the costs to develop for some platforms can be. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft's official for Windows Phone developers is probably the best place to start:
http://developer.windowsphone.com/en-us

And visit this GeekChamp developer's community, there is a lot of articles, tutorials and tips there!
http://www.geekchamp.com/resources

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view a good source of tutorial, are those with a complete series of all required points to get started. I recommend you Lynda.com tutorials:

www.lynda.com/Windows-Phone-training-tutorials/422-0.html